# RemoteObject inconsistent channel location

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, remoteobject

I have a swf which, for some reason, has four RemoteObjects pointing to the same ChannelId, but they are listing that channel as being at two different spots.  In four of the five RemoteObjects, everything behaves as expected, but in the fourth (WidgetService), the version on dev is switching from dev.context.root to loc.context.root.  To make matters more confusing, it only does this on the dev server (QA and production are fine, as are local builds).

The relevant information from the config files follows:

```
    #This is from build.properties, which is used by Ant 
    #to build the swf on the server
    flex.sdk.dir           = /path/to/sdk/flex_sdk_3.2.0.3958
    flex.sdk.bin.dir       = ${flex.sdk.dir}/bin
    flex.sdk.framework.dir = ${flex.sdk.dir}/frameworks
    flex.sdk.libs.dir      = ${flex.sdk.framework.dir}/libs
    flex.sdk.locale.dir    = ${flex.sdk.framework.dir}/locale/{locale}
    flex.sdk.locale        = en_US

    loc.context.root       = /somename-1.0.4.0000
    dev.context.root       = /dev-somename
    qa.context.root        = /somename
    prod.context.root      = /
    #this value is changed based on the build.
    context.root           = ${dev.context.root}
```

```
<!-- All of the RemoteObjects are directed here -->
<channel-definition id="my-amf" class="mx.messaging.channels.AMFChannel">
    <endpoint url="http://{server.name}:{server.port}/{context.root}/messagebroker/amf" class="flex.messaging.endpoints.AMFEndpoint"/>
</channel-definition>

<!-- A list of the services -->
<destination id="UserService">
    <properties>
        <factory>spring</factory>
        <source>userService</source>
    </properties>
    <channels>
        <channel ref="my-amf"></channel>
    </channels>
</destination>    

<destination id="SystemService">
    <properties>
        <factory>spring</factory>
        <source>systemService</source>
    </properties>
    <channels>
        <channel ref="my-amf"></channel>
    </channels>
</destination>    

<destination id="SessionService">
    <properties>
        <factory>spring</factory>
        <source>sessionService</source>
    </properties>
    <channels>
        <channel ref="my-amf"></channel>
    </channels>
</destination>    

<destination id="VistorService">
    <properties>
        <factory>spring</factory>
        <source>visitorService</source>
    </properties>
    <channels>
        <channel ref="my-amf"></channel>
    </channels>
</destination>    

<destination id="WidgetService">
    <properties>
        <factory>spring</factory>
        <source>widgetService</source>
    </properties>
    <channels>
        <channel ref="my-amf"></channel>
    </channels>
</destination>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that another developer built a swf which was loaded at run-time using the project's local configuration instead of the server configuration.